# Get div details on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a social feed page when a user can post something in his/her mind, I want to add a view count on this page, my problem is how can I count views on every social feed when the user scroll down the page

Comment: Lots of ways. What db are you using? This question needs some more information.

Comment: I'm using MYSQL, and Laravel homestead as my local environment

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

With this you can control what happens once an Element scrolls into view (or out of it). 
You can even define how many percent the element should be visible until the callback-function is executed.

First you create an Observer:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here we create an observer that triggers once the element is fully visible, we will define the callback-function later.

Then you have to set the target:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.social-media-post');
observer.observe(target);
```

Here you tell the browser to observe every Element with the class `social-media-post`

Then all that's left to do is to define what should happen once the element is visible, defining the callback-function:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    // here you increase the counter for each element
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi @cloned, I got some minor problems with regards the Intersection observer, I have 10 divs that have a class list that wraps inside a div. I've selected all the divs that has list class and my problem is when I scroll down only one div gets on the callback function.

Comment: Then I think the best would be to open a new question for this, detailing your problem and sharing your code so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I know what the problem is, Its because of jscroll plugin

Comment: If elements get added dynamically then you have to add them to your target and observe them too I think.